# JFrame Printing out not as expected. if loop trouble

Tags: java, swing, date

Sorry for the long code, didn't want to leave anything out.
Little explanation, I'm just trying to do a way where the user inputs a date to check there history between the two dates 
 now i have it working to an extent, it reads of a text document, which for each transactions has 8 lines that need to be printed if the date is between the dates
the Example document is structured as below:

```
######## START OF TRANSACTION ########
Name: name
DATE: 14/05/2015
Ammount: 100 
Address: address
Card Number: 123312
ExpiryDate: 123312 
######## END OF TRANSACTION ########
######## START OF TRANSACTION ########
Name: name 
DATE: 19/05/2015 
Ammount: 100 
Address: address 
Card Number: 123312
ExpiryDate: 123312 
######## END OF TRANSACTION ########
```

if i input the date 15-05-2015 to 16-05-2015 
i get:

```
######## START OF TRANSACTION ########
Name: name
DATE: 14/05/2015
Ammount: 100
Address: address
Card Number: 123312
ExpiryDate: 123312
null######## END OF TRANSACTION ########
######## START OF TRANSACTION ########
Name: name
DATE: 19/05/2015
Ammount: 105
Address: address
Card Number: 123312
null
```

1: what is with the NULL values guessing my loop
 2: why does it print the 19. even if i have the 16th in their it still prints the 19th....please help, I've been on this for awhile

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.text.ParseException;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.*;

    public class TopUpHistoryScreen extends JDialog {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextArea historyScreen;

    public TopUpHistoryScreen()
    {
    setPanels();

    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setSize(400, 450);
    setVisible(true);
}
public String Reader() {
    try {

        ArrayList<String> Trains = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = 0;
        String testing = "";
        File file = new File("TopUp.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            count += count;
            Trains.add(line + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            testing += line + "\n";
            //field.setText(line);


        }
        fileReader.close();
        return testing;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public String checkDates(String startDate, String endDate) {
    try {

        ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        int count = 0;
        int check = 0;
        String[] lineArray = new String[8];
        String DateSelected = "";
        String testing="";
        File file = new File("TopUp.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            lineArray[count] = line+"\n";

            if (count < 8){
                count ++;
            }

            if (count == 7){
                if(check == 1){
                testing += lineArray[0];
                testing += lineArray[1];
                testing += lineArray[2];
                testing += lineArray[3];
                testing += lineArray[4];
                testing += lineArray[5];
                testing += lineArray[6];
                testing += lineArray[7];
                check = 0;
                }
            }
            if (count == 7){
                count = 0;
                check = 0;
                lineArray = new String[8];
            }


            if (line.contains("DATE")){
                try {
            DateSelected = line.replace("DATE: ", "");
            Date MainDate = sdf.parse(DateSelected);
            Date SDate = sdf.parse(startDate);
            Date EDate = sdf.parse(endDate);
            if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)>=0 || MainDate.compareTo(EDate)<=0 ){ 

//is after Sdate and before eDate
                    check = 1;
                }
//              if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)<0){ //is Before SDate
//                  
//              }
//              if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)==0){ //is equal to mainDate
//                  
//              }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
            stringBuffer.append(line);

            Lines.add(line + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("\n");



        }
        fileReader.close();
        return testing;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setPanels()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    //JButton apply = new JButton("Select data area");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Okay!");
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
        }
    });
    JButton checkDate = new JButton("check dates");


    JLabel START = new JLabel("START DATE!");
    JLabel startDay = new JLabel("Day:");
    JTextField sDay = new JTextField();

    JLabel startMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
    JTextField sMonth = new JTextField();

    JLabel startYear = new JLabel("Year:");
    JTextField sYear = new JTextField("2015");

    JLabel END = new JLabel("END DATE!");

    JLabel endDay = new JLabel("Day:");
    JTextField eDay = new JTextField();

    JLabel endMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
    JTextField eMonth = new JTextField();

    JLabel endYear = new JLabel("Year:");
    JTextField eYear = new JTextField("2015");

    //JTextField Data = new JTextField();
    //JTextField touchOnTimeFieldminute = new JTextField();

    historyScreen = new JTextArea(10,20);
    JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(historyScreen);

    //mainPanel.add(SelectData);
     //mainPanel.add(SelectData);
    // mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
        mainPanel.add(START);
        mainPanel.add(startDay);
        mainPanel.add(sDay);
        mainPanel.add(startMonth);
        mainPanel.add(sMonth);
        mainPanel.add(startYear);
        mainPanel.add(sYear);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
        mainPanel.add(END);
        mainPanel.add(endDay);
        mainPanel.add(eDay);
        mainPanel.add(endMonth);
        mainPanel.add(eMonth);
        mainPanel.add(endYear);
        mainPanel.add(eYear);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
        mainPanel.add(checkDate);
    lowerPanel.add(scrolll);
    lowerPanel.add(exit);
    containerPanel.add(mainPanel);
    containerPanel.add(lowerPanel);

    add(containerPanel);
    checkDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

            String startday = sDay.getText();
            String startmonth = sMonth.getText();
            String startyear = sYear.getText();

            String endday = eDay.getText();
            String endmonth = eMonth.getText();
            String endyear = eYear.getText();

            String startDate = (startday+"/"+startmonth+"/"+startyear);
            String endDate = (endday+"/"+endmonth+"/"+endyear);

            String AnswerDates = checkDates(startDate,endDate);

            historyScreen.setText(AnswerDates);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting on the input/output as well.  It is hard to tell where it finishes, and your other explanations begin!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Edited to what i think you where asking... not to sure what else you wanted me to tell you its all in Jfield & Text

Comment: It's much more clear now, I would not have seen that *"if i input the date.."* was mixed amongst two 'data' sections.  On that subject, please make it simpler for those trying to help by making an MCVE.  That would require for you to hard code that initial data (then reduce the complexity and length of the code sample).

Comment: @AndrewThompson yea i knew it was a little to much to write. and its hard to focus on one section, but if i didn't have the other stuff in there i think it wouldn't make sense, i will try separate the code that needs to be highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys i got it this time, just incase someone looks at this later hahaha, it was because my for loop was ending at 7 instead of 8 and was saving no value into array [7], and also because the date check was doing || instead of && below is the updated class

```
public String checkDates(String startDate, String endDate) {
    try {

        ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        int count = 0;
        int check = 0;
        String[] lineArray = new String[8];
        String DateSelected = "";
        String testing="";
        File file = new File("TopUp.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            lineArray[count] = line+"\n";

            if (count < 8){
                count ++;
            }

            if (count == 8){
                if(check == 1){

                testing += lineArray[0];
                testing += lineArray[1];
                testing += lineArray[2];
                testing += lineArray[3];
                testing += lineArray[4];
                testing += lineArray[5];
                testing += lineArray[6];
                testing += lineArray[7];
                check = 0;
                }
            }
            if (count == 8){
                count = 0;
                check = 0;
                lineArray = new String[8];
            }


            if (line.contains("DATE")){
                try {
            DateSelected = line.replace("DATE: ", "");
            Date MainDate = sdf.parse(DateSelected);
            Date SDate = sdf.parse(startDate);
            Date EDate = sdf.parse(endDate);
            if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)>=0 && MainDate.compareTo(EDate)<=0 ){ 

//is after Sdate and before eDate
                    check = 1;
                }
//              if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)<0){ //is Before SDate
//                  
//              }
//              if(MainDate.compareTo(SDate)==0){ //is equal to mainDate
//                  
//

            }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
            stringBuffer.append(line);

            Lines.add(line + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("\n");



        }
        fileReader.close();
        return testing;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```